# Implementation of softmax derivative for matrix input

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, softmax

I followed this [blog post](https://e2eml.school/softmax.html) to implement a derivative of softmax function in a neural network.

```py
    def forward(x):
        e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True))
        softmax = e_x / np.sum(e_x, axis=1, keepdims=True)

        return softmax

    def backward(softmax, grad_output):
        shape = softmax.shape

        softmax = np.reshape(softmax, (1, -1))
        grad_output = np.reshape(grad_output, (1, -1))

        d_softmax = softmax * np.identity(softmax.size) - softmax.T @ softmax

        grad = (grad_output @ d_softmax).reshape(shape)

        return grad
```

This code works when `softmax` and `grad_output` have shape `(1, N)`, but fails when I provide inputs with shape `(batch_size, N)`. How to modify this function so that it accepts inputs that are matrices?

Answer (score 0):

I maybe wrong, but I think it is not meant to accept any inputs that are not (1xN), as softmax is an activation function thus it is applied onto the vector of the unactivated weighted sums, so by trying to make it accept any more than a 1xN, it doesnt really make sense, as the output of a single layer is always 1xC or Cx1.